# SQL query with in clause and get data with subsequent order according to name column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I am not sure if it is asked before, but the problem is like this.

```sql
+---------+---------------+------+-----------+
| item_id | name          | data |priority | expire |
+---------+---------------+------+-----------+
|      11 | decimal_queue |  data|    0 |      0 |
+---------+---------------+------+------+----+
```

Now, There are different type of queue, in the name `decimal_queue`, `single_queue`, `three_queue`, I want to get them one by one in `SELECT` query with limit of lets;s say `10`

So, first let's suppose item of `decimal_queue` then the next item `single_queue` then `three_queue` in this manner, also I want to limit total number to max `10` and the queue can be dynamic in number.

Is it achievable, I am also using PHP in backend, if that also solves to get array like that.

I tested - but not sure is it achievable, if yes - how to approach this

Comment: I tested... Please share what you've tested. Please provide sample data, expected output, thanks

Comment: LIMIT of 10 in total or 10 per queue?

Comment: what's the logic for ordering purely alpha or something else?

Comment: It is about processing queue items parallely - in PHP backend application, single `queue` will store `queue` items, `queue` the name `column` is created with PHP api, and items added to the particular queue, which stores data to `queue` table  

Now, the problem - is processing as `parallel queue`

Comment: @PaulBradbury what? Please show your expected output. I have no idea what you’re asking for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` to create a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and create a limit for your rows in a `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) AS rn
    FROM queues)
SELECT 
  item_id,
  name,
  data,
  priority,
  expire
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
ORDER BY rn, name
```

**Result:**

```
| item_id | name          | data | priority | expire |
|---------|---------------|------|----------|--------|
| 11      | decimal_queue | data | 0        | 0      |
| 12      | single_queue  | data | 2        | 1      |
| 13      | three_queue   | data | 0        | 0      |
| 14      | decimal_queue | data | 3        | 0      |
| 16      | single_queue  | data | 0        | 0      |
| 15      | three_queue   | data | 1        | 1      |
| 17      | decimal_queue | data | 3        | 1      |
| 19      | single_queue  | data | 0        | 1      |
| 20      | three_queue   | data | 3        | 0      |
| 18      | decimal_queue | data | 2        | 0      |
| 21      | single_queue  | data | 0        | 1      |
| 22      | three_queue   | data | 2        | 1      |
| 23      | decimal_queue | data | 1        | 0      |
| 24      | single_queue  | data | 1        | 0      |
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/N7ialKSQ).**

You can also reverse the order (or specify any order you like) by using the `FIELD` function instead of `name` in your `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY rn, FIELD(name,'three_queue','single_queue','decimal_queue')
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/LiBUOmTA).**

Comment: I wonder if four_queue would appear after three_queue or between decimal_queue and single_queue.

Comment: already ahead of you : ) ..I knew somebody would point that out, valid point though.